# Qt layout system (QTextEdit hasn't minimum size)

Tags: c++, qt

I have problem with Qt layout system. First pic is what i get and second is what i want.
I have one vertical splitter and two widgets inside. First widget has expanding policy and stretch factor to 1. Second has minimum height policy, minimumHeight 100 and stretch factor 0. Result after start should be second picture, but actually it is first picture and i need manually drag splitter down. Where is problem?

[image: What i get]

[image: What i want]

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QSizePolicy sp;

    QSplitter * splitter = new QSplitter(Qt::Vertical);
    splitter->setHandleWidth(1);
    splitter->setChildrenCollapsible(false);
    sp.setHorizontalPolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding);
    sp.setVerticalPolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding);
    splitter->setSizePolicy(sp);

    QWidget * topWidget = new QWidget(splitter);
    sp.setVerticalStretch(1);
    topWidget->setSizePolicy(sp);
    topWidget->setMinimumHeight(200);

    QWidget * bottomWidget = new QWidget(splitter);
    sp.setVerticalStretch(0);
    bottomWidget->setSizePolicy(sp);


    QTextEdit * edit = new QTextEdit();
    edit->setFrameStyle(QFrame::NoFrame);
    edit->setMinimumSize(0, 100);
    sp.setVerticalPolicy(QSizePolicy::Minimum);
    edit->setSizePolicy(sp);

    QVBoxLayout * bottomWidgetLayout = new QVBoxLayout(bottomWidget);
    bottomWidgetLayout->addWidget(edit);

    bottomWidget->setLayout(bottomWidgetLayout);

    splitter->setStretchFactor(0, 1);
    splitter->setStretchFactor(1, 0);
    this->centralWidget()->layout()->addWidget(splitter);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

as you can see [here](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qsizepolicy.html#Policy-enum) `QSizePolicy::Minimum` has `GrowFlag`, while you need policy with `ShrinkFlag`, try to use `QSizePolicy::Maximum` instead if you want to tell widget to shrink.

Comment: i want GrowFlag policy, but only through splitter when user want, that's why i am setting QSizePolicy::Minimum and stretch factor 0, then if there is other widget with QSizePolicy::Expandable and stretchFactor > 0, it gets whole "unused" space, so my TextEdit should get only 100px in height.

Comment: start screen should look like second picture

Comment: splitter->setStretchFactor(0, 1);
    splitter->setStretchFactor(1, 0);

these lines look bad

Answer (score 0):

`QSplitter` has some really odd behavior when it comes to sizes, but you can achieve your desired look in the second screenshot through use of the `setSizes(const QList<int>&)` function.  Documentation [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsplitter.html#setSizes).

The documentation is a little unclear (IMO) about how the sizes are handled, but the following quote is most important:

> The overall size of the splitter widget is not affected. Instead, any additional/missing space is distributed amongst the widgets according to the relative weight of the sizes.

You can take advantage of this, in combination with your second widget's minimum size of 100 pixels to achieve either a ratio (i.e. 3:2 where the top widget is 50% larger than the bottom) or to force the second widget to its minimum size.

To achieve an approximate ratio of 3:2, put this in place of the two `setStretchFactor()` calls:

```
QList<int> sizes;
sizes << 300 << 200;
splitter->setSizes(sizes);
```

To force the second widget to its minimum size of 100 pixels, use this instead:

```
QList<int> sizes;
sizes << 100 << 1;  //Really, the first size could be any large value you choose
splitter->setSizes(sizes);
```

In either case, it doesn't matter how large your window actually is because Qt will  distribute the available space according to the ratio between the sizes you provide in the `setSizes()` call.